# Haskell Coverage - HPC can not find Main

Tags: haskell, code-coverage

I have a program that is built up of many C++ and Haskell files.
I compile all of the Haskell with `-fhpc` flag so that I may run coverage tests on it.

After compiling is finished,  I run the program and several `.tix` files are generated.

The problem: I attempt to run `hpc markup build/Server --srcdir=.` for instance.
It will then generate some files, but fail prematurely:

```
Writing: file1.hs.html
Writing: file2.hs.html
Writing: file3.hs.html
hpc: can not find Main in ["./.hpc"]
```

The directory `.hpc` exists, and it does contain a file called `Main.mix` alongside other `.mix` files.

I've noticed some people reporting the same issues on IRC chat logs, but nowhere have I found a solution for this.
Does anyone have this experience with hpc?

Edit: How I compile
I have a fairly complicated compiling scheme.
I actually just [wrote it down in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424615/how-to-link-custom-object-file-with-haskell-library/25660388#25660388).

I use a very specific package library which I specify explicitly by using `--no-user-package-db` and `--package-db=/usr/local/ghc-7.6.3-200814`.
That [directory's listings is available here](http://pastebin.com/uWuwqgAA)

Comment: how did you compile? (ghc directly - what options? or cabal - show the .cabal file)

Comment: I have a fairly complicated compiling scheme. I actually just [wrote it down in another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424615/how-to-link-custom-object-file-with-haskell-library/25660388#25660388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it running today.
I changed my compilation to have no optimizations at all.
I ran my server from the base project directory by running `./build/Server ...`

I generated a list of all my modules to be included using sed inside Make.

(My directory structure is the same as the module names.
For example, the filename `haskell/Database/Module/Server/Server.lhs` will become Database.Module.Server.Server.)

```
includify = $(foreach pkg,$(1), --include=$(pkg))
MODULES = $(shell find haskell -name "*.lhs" | sed -e "s/\.lhs\$$//g" | sed -e "s/^haskell\///g" | sed -e "s/\//\./g")
INCLUDES = $(call includify,$(MODULES))
```

and then created the target (inside Make again)

```
@echo "WRITING coverage/result.xml"
@hpc report Server srcdir=build $(INCLUDES) --xml-output > build/coverage/result.xml
@echo "WRITING coverage HTML FILES"
@hpc markup Server srcdir=build $(INCLUDES) --destdir=build/coverage
```

And this is how I solved my issues.